# How to layout a form like this with CSS and maybe some JS?

Tags: html, css

I have a design that has form labels inline to the left of text fields. The labels are all different widths. I need to have the right edge of the text field right aligned.

**Currently the fields look like this. See how the right edge is not aligned?**

Name: ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___**

Address: ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___**

City: ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___**

**I need it to look something like this...**

Name: ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

Address: ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___**

City: ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*____**

Can I do this without having to set a fixed width on each text field?

Comment: You could put them in a container and set the width to 100%.

Comment: Could you post the code that you have now? That would be helpful for anyone trying to give a quality answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Granted it's probably not the most efficient approach, but you could make a separate table for each field.

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name:</th>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Address:</th>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>City:</th>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

​
**CSS**

```
table { width: 300px; }
td { border-bottom: 1px solid black; }
th { width: 1em; }

input { width: 100%; border: none; }
input:focus { outline: none; }
```

​    ​
JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BUy6f/2/
​

Answer (score -1):

You can use a borderless table, like this: [Exemple](http://jsfiddle.net/A84c2/)

Comment: The left edge of the textboxes should not be aligned, but start right after the text.

Comment: I thought he was talking about the "input text", it is as he showed in the example.

Comment: In the example, the input text do not start at the same vertical (x) point, they only end the same.

Comment: Yeah.. I need the text field to start immediately after the label. And the right edge of the text field needs to be the same (x) position for all fields. So the right edge will be straight and not jagged.

Comment: Oh, sorry, did not realize it. I think you can go manually setting the pixels yourself, http://jsfiddle.net/A84c2/1/